# Can flags on meta show up on the main site?

Tags: feature-request

I do check meta reasonably often, but not nearly as often as the main site. It'd be great if flags here showed up somehow on the main site, so nothing goes unreviewed for too long.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109827/combine-flag-and-edit-queues-from-main-and-meta-on-se-2-0-sites